# SendEmailError Messaging.SendEmailError[getTargetObjectId=null;]

Tags: error-messages, singleemailmessage

I've written a method which should send messages to the current user, the System Administrator, and a list of other addresses that I specify.

```
public static void sendErrorEmail(String body)
{
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage errorMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        errorMail.setSubject('Error E-mail Subjectline');
        errorMail.setPlainTextBody(body);
        String[] sendTo = new String[]{};
        sendTo.add(UserInfo.getUserEmail());
        Profile adminProfile = [Select Id, Name from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1];
        if(UserInfo.getProfileId() != adminProfile.Id) 
            sendTo.add([Select Email, ProfileId from User where ProfileId = :adminProfile.Id LIMIT 1].Email);

        errorMail.setToAddresses(sendTo);

        //errorMail.setCcAddresses(devEmails);
        errorMail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
        System.debug(errorMail.getTargetObjectId());
        System.debug(sendTo);


        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] eResults = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{errorMail}, false);
        System.debug(eResults);
}
```

However, this is giving me the following error (copied from debug log):

> DEBUG|(Messaging.SendEmailResult[getErrors=(Messaging.SendEmailError[getTargetObjectId=null;]);isSuccess=false;]

I've tried this without specifying setTargetObjectId as well, as it should not be necessary given that I am not using a template, but the same error occurs. When I checked the debug log to make sure that the target object and sendTo list were not null, they both appeared correct.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: What error did you get when you commented **errorMail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());** out?  I feel like you shouldn't have that line in your code without a template.

Comment: Exactly the same error. I'm just as confused as you, @dphil

Comment: What happens when you comment out this line: errorMail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId()); and the debug right below it

Comment: This would seem to indicate that the problem could be with a bad email address on one of your recipients: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008xNFIAY

Comment: Got it- if body = null, this error was thrown. Which is really bizarre error handling on Salesforce's part.

Comment: Yes, as @greenstork also has noted this is throwing if the recipients email addresses invalid also. So there are number of points to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code snippet you are not using an email template. You just need to send a single email to multiple users. So there is no need of specifying `setTargetObjectId(ID)`. This is an optional which need to be used [if using a template](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setTargetObjectId). So remove both below lines and retry it.

```
 errorMail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
 System.debug(errorMail.getTargetObjectId());
```

Comment: According to the docs, it's actually optional to include regardless of whether or not there is a template.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me in anonymous apex; note the setSaveAsActivity. I agree with @highfive that setTargetObjectId() only has utility in supporting merge fields within a template and hence for straight plain text email, has no relevance.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);
email.setToAddresses(new List<String> {'crop1645@fubar.com'});
email.setCcAddresses(new List<String>{});
email.setbccAddresses(new List<String> {});
email.setSubject('some subject');
email.setPlainTextBody('some body');
email.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
email.setSaveAsActivity(false);  // required if sending to a user
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that 'body' was null in the cases I was testing. While I'm not sure why Salesforce gives the error it does for this problem, adding a statement along the lines of

```
if(body == null) body = 'UNKNOWN ERROR';
```

prior to setting the body of the e-mail solves the issue. Thank you everyone for your help. There are evidently a number of other problems unrelated to the TargetObjectId which can also cause this error, including having an invalid e-mail address in the To or CC fields. Thanks to @greenstork for that one.